# parity bias for trees?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $t(n)$ denote the number of unlabeled unrooted trees on n vertices, e.g. $t(4)=2$ .
Next denote by $\operatorname{even}(n)$ the number of such trees having an even number of endpoints.

Similarly, define $\operatorname{odd}(n)$ for an odd number of endpoints, e.g. $\operatorname{even}(4) = \operatorname{odd}(4) = 1$ .

Other examples are: $\operatorname{even}(8) = 12 > 11 = \operatorname{odd}(8)$ and $\operatorname{even}(9) = 25 > \operatorname{odd}(9) = 22$. In fact, for small number of vertices, it always seems to be the case that $\operatorname{even}(n)$
is at least as large as $\operatorname{odd}(n)$ .

Questions:

(1) Are there any values of $n$ for which  $\operatorname{odd}(n) > \operatorname{even}(n)$ ?

(2) Is there a generating function $T(x,y)$ for unlabeled unrooted
                 trees according to the number of endpoints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to the rooted case while we wait for the experts to
join in.

The  species of  rooted  unlabelled trees  with  endpoints marked  has
specification
$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{U}\mathcal{Z} +
\mathcal{Z}\mathfrak{M}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{T}).$$

This gives the functional equation for the generating function
$$T(z, u) = uz+
z\left(-1+\exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{T(z^l, u^l)}{l} 
\right)\right).$$
An alternate form is
$$T(z, u) = uz+
z\left(-1+\prod_{l\ge 1} \exp\left(\frac{T(z^l, u^l)}{l}
\right)\right).$$

This gives the following recurrence for the coefficients $T_n.$
We have $T_1 = u$ and for $n\ge 2$ we have
$$T_n = [z^{n-1}]
\left(-1 +
\exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{T(z^l, u^l)}{l}\right)\right).$$
These coeffients are polynomials in $u.$

Start by observing that if
$$A(z, u) = \sum_{n\ge 1} A_n z^n =
\sum_{l\ge 1} \frac{T(z^l, u^l)}{l}$$
then
$$A_n = \sum_{l|n} \frac{\left.T_{n/l}\right|_{u=u^l}}{l}.$$

Re-writing the functional equation in terms of $A(z)$ yields
$$T(z, u) = uz + z(-1 + \exp A(z, u))$$
and differentiating with respect to $z$ we get
$$T'(z, u) = u-1 + \exp A(z, u) + z \exp A(z, u) A'(z, u)$$
which is
$$T'(z, u) = u-1 + \frac{T(z,u)}{z} - u + 1 +
(T(z, u)- uz + z) A'(z,u)$$
or $$z T'(z, u) = T(z, u) + z (T(z, u)- uz + z) A'(z,u).$$

Extracting cofficients we obtain
$$n T_n = T_n + [z^{n-1}] (T(z, u)- uz + z) A'(z,u)
\\ = T_n + (1-u) [z^{n-2}] A'(z, u) +
\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} T_{n-1-k} (k+1) A_{k+1}
\\ = T_n + (1-u) (n-1) A_{n-1}  +
\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (k+1) A_{k+1} T_{n-1-k}.$$

This gives for $T_n$ with $n\ge 2$ the recurrence
$$T_n = (1-u) A_{n-1}  +
\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (k+1) A_{k+1} T_{n-1-k}.$$

Note that the  $A_n$ are defined recursively in terms  of the $T_n$ as
above.

Setting $u=1$ in the polynomials $T_n$ yields the sequence:
$$1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 20, 48, 115, 286, 719, 1842, 4766, 12486, 32973,
\\ 87811, 235381, 634847, 1721159, 4688676, 12826228,\ldots$$
which points us to [OEIS A000081](https://oeis.org/A000081) where
we learn that we indeed have the correct values.

Here are the first few distributions of the number of endpoints starting
with the tree on one node:
$$u
\\u
\\{u}^{2}+u
\\{u}^{3}+2\,{u}^{2}+u
\\{u}^{4}+3\,{u}^{3}+4\,{u}^{2}+u
\\{u}^{5}+4\,{u}^{4}+8\,{u}^{3}+6\,{u}^{2}+u
\\{u}^{6}+5\,{u}^{5}+14\,{u}^{4}+18\,{u}^{3}+9\,{u}^{2}+u$$

Now evidently the count of trees with an even number of endpoints
is given by
$$\frac{1}{2} \left(\left.T_n\right|_{u=1}+
\left.T_n\right|_{u=-1}\right)$$
and for odd number of endpoints
$$\frac{1}{2} \left(\left.T_n\right|_{u=1}-
\left.T_n\right|_{u=-1}\right).$$

This  gives  the following  sequence  of  counts  for even  number  of
endpoints:
$$0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 24, 57, 144, 360, 923, 2382, 6246, 16486, 43917,
\\ 117692, 317447, 860574, 2344396, 6413119, \ldots$$
and for odd number of endpoints
$$1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 10, 24, 58, 142, 359, 919, 2384, 6240, 16487, 43894,
\\ 117689, 317400, 860585, 2344280, 6413109, \ldots$$

The difference between these two goes like this:
$$ -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 2, 1, 4, -2, 6, -1, 23, 3, 47, -11, 116,
\\ 10, 340, 13, 783, -14, 2181, 248, 5811, 321, 15026, 1335, 41660,
\\ 4938, 111237, 11384, 301857, 39610, 831896, 112673, 2263974, 315069,
\\ 6252982, 962897, 17280616, 2699066, 47760078, 7830950, 132931348,
\\ 22759720, 369884919, 64726655, 1032244936, 187331836, 2889218776,
\\ 537613196, 8093813288, 1540657359, 22732097026, 4436185030,
\\ 63945607606, 12718488294\ldots$$
so in the case of rooted unlabeled trees there would seem to be a bias
towards even numbers of endpoints.

The  following  Maple code  was  used  to  compute these  values.   It
includes a  basic routine that can  be used to  verify the polynomials
for small $n$ say $n\le 7.$

```
with(numtheory);

T_basic :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local gf, q, k, p, term;

    if n=0 then return 0 fi;
    if n=1 then return u fi;

    gf := 1;
    for q to n-1 do
        for k to q do
            term :=
            add((u^k*z^q)^m, m=0..floor((n-1)/q));

            p := coeff(T_basic(q), u, k);
            gf := gf*term^p;
        od;
    od;

    coeftayl(gf, z=0, n-1);
end;

T :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local k, s, A;

    if n=0 then return 0 fi;
    if n=1 then return u fi;

    A := n -> add(subs(u=u^l, T(n/l))/l,
                  l in divisors(n));

    s := (1-u)*A(n-1);

    s := s + 1/(n-1)*
    add((k+1)*A(k+1)*T(n-1-k), k=0..n-2);

    expand(s);
end;

T_all := n -> subs(u=1, T(n));

T_even := n -> 1/2*(subs(u=1, T(n)) + subs(u=-1, T(n)));
T_odd := n -> 1/2*(subs(u=1, T(n)) - subs(u=-1, T(n)));
```

This material is inspired by Harary and Palmer,
*Graphical Enumeration.*

**Addendum Sat Dec 27 2014.** We can verify the above results with Maple's **combstruct package.** It will even compute the functional equation for you (univariate version).

The following Maple code will do the trick for values of $n$ at most twelve.

```
with(combstruct);

gf :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local trees, leaves;

    trees := { T=Union(Prod(Z, U), Prod(Z, Set(T, 1<= card))),
               Z=Atom, U=Epsilon };

    leaves :=
    proc(struct)
        if type(struct, function) then
            return add(leaves(op(q, struct)), q=1..nops(struct));
        fi;

        if struct = Z then return 0 fi;
        return 1;
    end;

    add(u^leaves(t), t in allstructs([T, trees], size=n));
end;
```

This will compute the following generating function for trees on $11$ nodes:
$${u}^{10}+9\,{u}^{9}+52\,{u}^{8}+185\,{u}^{7}+416\,{u}^{6}+563\,{u}^{5}+
429\,{u}^{4}+161\,{u}^{3}+25\,{u}^{2}+u.$$
This matches the value from the recurrence.

The command

```
seq(count([T, trees], size=n), n=1..15);
```

will produce the
coefficients of the univariate generating function for this problem matching the
values shown above.